# "Sophisticated" filtering of an array-typed field in Mongo Aggregation framework?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, nosql

I would like to `$match` by a field having an array, filled with only `false` values. The array can be of any size. How can I do that please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given data like:

```
> db.so.insert({data: [true, true, false, false], name: 'A'})
> db.so.insert({data: [false, false, false], name: 'B'})
> db.so.insert({data: [false, false, true], name: 'C'})
> db.so.insert({data: [false], name: 'D'})
```

You can use `$nin`:

```
> db.so.aggregate({$match: { data : { $nin: [true]  }} })
{
        "result" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("51c1f654e376a9016c5a9a6d"),
                        "data" : [
                                false,
                                false,
                                false
                        ],
                        "name" : "B"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("51c1f65fe376a9016c5a9a6f"),
                        "data" : [
                                false
                        ],
                        "name" : "D"
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

You could use `$and` to make sure that the array exists if you wanted as well.

If you could precalculate the value of this computation (`onlyFalse=true`), it might be faster to operate (depending on amount of data, etc.)

Comment: Thanks, adding the reference for clarity: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/nin/